# TYPO3: what abstract to use for articles?

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

I'm just wondering how to implement pages with articles in TYPO3. I've seen `News admin` and `tt_news` package, so it seems these could be used too. But articles are not exactly news, so I wonder if using `tt_news` for this purpose isn't just some dirty hack and I wonder if there is some cleaner concept to be used for articles.

With article I mean something on certain topic which is not quickly outdated (contrary to news), the publish date is not so important, and the sort order of articles would not necessarily be by date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, using `tt_news` is **not** dirty hack, it was used through long years for *veeeeery* different purposes and for now it's best solution I think (without writing custom extensions). What's more that's not only my thoughts this extension has the biggest number of downloads from TYPO3 repository.

Using different templates, categories and `RealURL` settings you can 'mask' that is `tt_news` in one place and use it for an example to build simple product's catalogue with lists and single views.

It also offers possibility to use `hooks` for extending ie. by adding additional template `markers` so instead writing the ext from the scratch, you just only write simple hooks functionality and that's all. As far as I remember there are even sample hooks in tt_news source code, so you just need to copy it into your own ext.

PS. by default tt_news doesn't support manual sorting (it sorts from newest to oldest from the range), however you'll find few extensions in repository to add this functionality.

Comment: Thank you Marcus for quick and detailed answer! That's what I needed to know.